# Passing parameters url in Select2

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to create tagging and use ajax to show *the most used* tags, then I use [Select2](https://select2.github.io) plugin for handle this case. I got stucked when calling my JSON Data here my **javascript code** so far:

```
$("#tags").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "api/v1/tags/",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        quietMillis: 150,
        allowClear: true,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
               tags: params.term
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                    return { 
                        id: obj.id, 
                        text: obj.slug 
                    };
                })
            };
        }
    },
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Search or insert tags",
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
});
```

It is returning this error:

> GET http://lesson1.dev/api/v1/tags/?tags=mykeyword 404 (Not Found)

I Save my JSON Data in this directories `/api/v1/tags/a` **...**  `/api/v1/tags/z`

I was just wondering how to change the parameters url `?tags=keyword` in the Select2 Parameters into `/keyword`, I've looking for in the vendor document but I don't get anything. Can anyone help me? I need your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your script, but in API you're trying to access. It returns 404, which means you've either *provided wrong URL* or *Resource is simply not there*.

Try to concatenate **Keyword** value directly to **URL** string as follows, instead of using **data** parameter:

```
$("#tags").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "api/v1/tags/" + keywordValue,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    quietMillis: 150,
    allowClear: true,
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
          return { 
            id: obj.id, 
            text: obj.slug 
          };
        })
      };
    }
  },
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Search or insert tags",
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Kamilius, thanks for help. Yeah i've trying that before. i use keyup() jQuery method for concatenate the Keyword and URL. But nothing show there.

Comment: @Alex You want autocomplete or something? Because I don't, actually, see another reason for taking input value with each keypress.

Comment: ooh sorry, yes sir i want to create autocomplete tag with Select2 Plugin, If you dont mid, please take a look the [Select2 Tags Example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) there :)

Comment: It seems, like in order to use this plugin, you should change a way, in which your backend works. tags should receive a query parameter upon which - to give you appropriate info in return. The URL you're using during select2 initialization - can not be changed in future without select reinit.  For now plugin automatically adds '?q=VALUE_HERE' parameter while you're trying to type anything into your "search" input

Comment: Hi @Kamilius thanks for the great answer. Yes we change the backend way to what this plugin needs for added `parameters`there! Thankyou :)